# Migration- Jira to Azure DevOps

Tags: migration

How to I migrate all stories (current sprint and historical data), comments and attachments from Jira to Azure DevOps? We just bough DevOps and would like to move all jira contents to DevOps.

Thanks
AA

Comment: https://peterrombouts.nl/2019/08/09/migrating-from-jira-to-azure-devops/ gives good hints

Answer (score 7):

Solidify Labs has a [JIRA to Azure DevOps migration tool](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=solidify-labs.jira-devops-migration) available in the Visual Studio Marketplace.

Some of the capabilities include ([more here](https://github.com/solidify/jira-azuredevops-migrator)):

- Export Jira issues from Jira queries
- Map users from Jira to users in Azure DevOps/TFS
- Migrate work item field data
- Migrate links and attachments
- Migrate history

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to do but it will take some custom tooling.

If you are familiar with PowerShell you can use [JiraPS](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/JiraPS/2.9.0) and [AzurePipelinesPS](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/AzurePipelinesPS/1.0.55) to get data from jira and post the data to Azure DevOps. If you have issues with either module feel free to open an issue on the project's GitHub page.

Edit: 
Some helpful JiraPS commands: 
New-JiraSession - Open a jira session
Get-JiraIssue - Returns a jira issue with all its custom fields and data

Comment: It would be useful if you would give some detail *how* those PowerShell solutions could be used for getting JIRA data and posting to DevOps.

Answer (score 0):

App named TFS4JIRA can help with your problem.
It makes possible to do one time migration and as well scheduled synchronizations both ways. Works for cloud and server instances of Azure and Jira.
You can check it there: [TFS4JIRA](https://spartez.com/products/tfs4jira)

Core features:

- synchronize issues (with all mapped fields there)
- map users (f.e. assigned to field)
- synchronize comments, attachments, web links
- issue/item relation links .

More info you can find here: [documentation](https://confluence.spartez.com/display/TFS4JIRA/About+TFS4JIRA)

It's commercial app, but for 30 days you can evaluate this software.